# How to count how many times a result has occurred?

Tags: python, tweepy

I am running a sentiment analysis by using twitter and I am having some difficulties on:
Counting how many 'Positive', 'Negative' and 'Neutral' results I have.

Any help will be me more than appreciated.

Please take a look at my code:

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob

consumer_key = ''
consumer_key_secret = ''

access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_key_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.search('stackoverflow')

for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
    if analysis.sentiment[0]>0:
        print ('Positive')
    elif analysis.sentiment[0]<0:
        print('Negative')
    else:
        print ('Neutral')
```

Comment: Where does `pandas` come into play here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just create variables that keep track of how many labels were in the data. Something like this:

```
pos, neg, neu = 0, 0, 0
for tweet in public_tweets:
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    if analysis.sentiment[0]>0:
        pos += 1
    elif analysis.sentiment[0]<0:
        neg += 1
    else:
        neu += 1
print("positive: {}\nnegative: {}\nneutral: {}".format(pos,neg,neu))
```

Regarding the result dataframe, I was not sure what kind of data you want to save, so could not give a good answer for that.